# How to pass parameters that contain a dollar sign to a program in Powershell? / Remote Connection Problems

Tags: powershell, remote-access

I recently started to learn Powershell. My problem is that I'm trying to run a powershell script to unfreeze a remote machine, but one of the parameters of Time Freeze contains a dollar sign. How do I do that?

Basically what I need to do is to run the following command:

```
cmd.exe /c "C:\Program Files\Toolwiz Time Freeze 2017\ToolwizTimeFreeze.exe" /unfreeze /usepass=$password
```

Where the dollar sign is part of the password.
If I run it on the powershell console directly on the remote machine, it works **(I just have to add single quotes around $password)**. But when I try to run the script from my local machine, it gets stuck on it and I have to Ctrl C to cancel it.

The script in question is this:

```
$User = "user"
$PWord = ConvertTo-SecureString "password" -AsPlainText -Force
$Ip = Read-Host -Prompt 'Insira o IP da maquina de destino:'
$Cred = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $User, $PWord
$sess = New-PSSession -Credential $Cred -ComputerName $Ip

Enter-PSSession $sess

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Ip -ScriptBlock { cmd.exe /c "C:\Program Files\Toolwiz Time Freeze 2017\ToolwizTimeFreeze.exe" /unfreeze /usepass=$password} -Credential $Cred

Remove-PSSession $sess
Exit-PSSession
```

I tried using Start-Process -Filepath and & to run the Time Freeze but it doesn't work neither (the script is executed but nothing happens at all), but when I try to run other commands like creating a new folder on the remote machine or restarting it, it works perfectly.

I don't know what else to try.

> Edit1: I tried to pass the parameter with the single quotes and I also
> tried using -argumentlist, but it doesn't work neither.
>
> Edit2: If I run the script locally, it works perfectly, even on the remote machine. But when I try to run it remotely it doesn't work. It seems very strange to me because I can run other commands remotely succesfully, but with this one I'm having troubles.
>
> Edit3: I forgot to update the question here, but I solved it. The problem wasn't about the password after all. I discovered by chance that in my script I had to stop the TimeFreeze proccess before I could call it again, otherwise I'd got stuck on it. So that's how I solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried escaping the $ in the password?:

```
/usepass="`$password"
```

No idea if this works, if not you could assign the password to a variable then provide that as an argument

```
 $mypassword = "`$password"
```

Comment: I tried both but they didn't work. I still get stuck running the command and I have to Ctrl C to cancel it.

Answer (score 0):

If possible, try to wrap all of the arguments you're passing to `cmd.exe` up into a variable prior to calling `Invoke-Command`.  Then you can pass the variable via `-ArgumentList`.

Here's a little example where i'm placing all my arguments into a `$params` variable and then passing it into the `ScriptBllock` of `InvokeCommand`.  Note that you need to add the `param()` section at the top to accept your the variable you pass in via `-ArgumentList`.

```
$params = @("/c ipconfig /all")
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Computer -Credential $Cred -ScriptBlock { 
    param(
        $params
    )
    Write-Host "We passed in the following parameters: '$params'"
    & "cmd.exe" $params 
} -ArgumentList $params
```

Comment: I tried doing it your way, but now I get this error:

'C:\Program' nÆo ' reconhecido como um comando interno
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: ('C:\Program' nÆ...comando interno:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

ou externo, um programa oper vel ou um arquivo em lotes.

I tried putting quotes also around the .exe path, but it is still not recognized

Answer (score 0):

If you are running this from PowerShell, you need to wrap quotes around values with spaces and escape the dollar sign in PowerShell and CMD.

```
$sb = { cmd.exe /c """C:\Program Files\Toolwiz Time Freeze 2017\ToolwizTimeFreeze.exe"" /unfreeze /usepass=\`$password"}
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Ip -ScriptBlock $sb -Credential $Cred
```

Comment: I'm still getting stucked running it. I don't think the problem is with the dollar sign anymore. Because if I run the script locally on the machine, it works fine. But when I try to run it remotely the command keeps running until I stop it manually using Ctrl C.